# Google Maps Javascript API v3 Heatmap Not Displaying

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

For some reason the Map wont display.... can't really figure out why.

Below is the code, for some reason the map is just not displaying...  This is my first time doing heatmaps with the Google Maps API v3 API so I'm a bit lost.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%">
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Heatmap</title>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=visualization"></script>
<style type="text/css">
 html { height: 100% }
 body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
 #map { height: 200px; width: 100% }
   </style>  
</head>
<body onload="initialize()" style="height: 100%;>
<div id="map" style="height: 600px; width: 800px;"></div>
<script>
    var map, pointarray, heatmap;
    var callsForService = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(42.2861624, -85.5813606), 
new google.maps.LatLng(42.3033738, -85.583591), 
new google.maps.LatLng(42.2453713, -85.584707), 
new google.maps.LatLng(42.3034079, -85.5973274), 
new google.maps.LatLng(42.249651, -85.595145), 
new google.maps.LatLng(42.2897601, -85.5858846), 
new google.maps.LatLng(42.321433, -85.551406), 
new google.maps.LatLng(42.2848497, -85.5906321), 
new google.maps.LatLng(42.2916942, -85.5818942), 
new google.maps.LatLng(42.3033738, -85.583591), 
new google.maps.LatLng(42.3061913, -85.5962831), 
new google.maps.LatLng(42.321433, -85.551406), 
new google.maps.LatLng(42.2917069, -85.5872286), 
    ];
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.2800153,-85.5828371),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
            mapOptions);

        pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(callsForService);

        heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
            data: pointArray
        });

        heatmap.setMap(map);
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a missing double-quote:

```
<body onload="initialize()" style="height: 100%;">
------------------------------------------------^
```

Also  remove the trailing comma in `callsForService`